# How can I render a child partial inside its parents partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, render, partial

I have tables of venues, reviews and comments where a venue can have many reviews and a review can have many comments.

The reviews themselves are shown as partials on the venues show page using:

```
<%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @venue.reviews %>
```

I thought using this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => @review.comments %>
```

inside the review partial would succesfully show the comments for that particular review but its just not displaying anything and giving no errors.

using `<%= review.comments.count %>` in the review partial does correctly show the number of comments added and checking the comments records in the console shows they have the correct foreign keys.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: did you tried changing `@review` to `review` in second one?

Comment: @Rubish Gupta, thanks for the response, yea I tried that it gives a RoutingError in Venues#show No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :review_id=>#<Review id: nil, title: nil, etc etc error.

Comment: can you gist the error ?

Comment: @Rubish Gupta, copying it over to a gist I noticed I'd messed up the comment partial using <%= link_to comment.body, [@review, comment] %> instead of just <%= link_to comment.body %> so removing the @ works. Thanks very much! add it as an answer and I'll give it a tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"did you tried changing @review to review in second one? – rubish Jul 25 at 22:48"